# pandas read_fwf and read_csv reading a multi-column txt file as a single column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file that looks like this :

```
  Record        Yhat    Residual         Hat
       1      6.7848     -0.6289      0.3030E-01
       2      6.7833     -0.3190E-01  0.3035E-01
       3      6.7829     -0.7528E-01  0.3036E-01
       4      6.7848      0.2131      0.3035E-01
       5      6.7837     -0.3270      0.3035E-01
```

with
`df = pd.read_fwf('/dev/y.yht', sep= " ",delimiter = "\t" )`
and `print(df)` i get :

```
           Record        Yhat    Residual         Hat
0           1      6.7848     -0.6289      0.3030E-01
1           2      6.7833     -0.3190E-01  0.3035E-01
2           3      6.7829     -0.7528E-01  0.3036E-01
3           4      6.7848      0.2131      0.3035E-01
4           5      6.7837     -0.3270      0.3035E-01
```

So everything *looks* okay.

but if i print df[0] i get a `KeyError: 0` ; `print(df.columns)` shows that there is only 1 column!

```
Index(['  Record        Yhat    Residual         Hat'], dtype='object')
```

I would like to read the file as a normal dataframe. not sure where its going wrong! The same thing is happening when i run read_csv; only one column is being read into the df with *all* of the data.

Comment: try `pd.read_fwf('/dev/y.yht',delimiter = "\s+" )`

Comment: [read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) might be better here: `pd.read_table('/dev/y.yht', delim_whitespace=True)`

Comment: Double check your columns @neutrino you probably still have some extra whitespace in your column names. if you use "\s+" as the delimiter.